# Printing lines without overwriting user input that has not yet been submitted in terminal using C

Tags: c, command-line, terminal, printf

Is it possible to print output to the terminal using C so that a user's incomplete input remains unaltered?

The use case is a multi-threaded program that outputs bulk results while awaiting user input for the next task. The issue is that whilst typing input back into the program, whenever the program outputs another line, the incomplete input gets swept up in the lines of output.

All ideas are welcome

Comment: I think the only way is to use screen addressing (moving the cursor around) to output without overwriting user text, then move the cursor in the previous position again.

Comment: `Is it possible` ? Yes. The real issue is to do so in a 1/reliable 2/portable way. A naive terminal-only solution is very easy to break: resizing your window or very long input is often enough. That is why it is usually best to rely on a library such as `ncurses` to take care of the difficult stuff.

Comment: Yes it is possible. ncurses was written in C and does this. Should *you* do this by yourself? No. You should use ncurses.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details what the user is expected to type. Is it some command that has to be processed when the uses presses the return key? How long can the command be? If it can be more than one line, is it required that you can see the complete command? Should the user be able to use the cursor keys or similar to edit the input?

Comment: It sounds like you have multiple threads performing I/O on the terminal. Don’t do that. Synchronize all output with the I/O thread, so that a single thread can manage I/O properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very basic problem is that user typing some input is independent from *all* of your threads running, from sight of your programme, it looks pretty much like another thread generating data.

Now you are in the trouble that you by some means need to synchronise both your programme and the user. So you need to get into single control of the screen.

> All ideas are welcome.

Well, here's the idea (however, you *will* produce non-portable codeas relying on OS-specific means):

- Read user input without getting it printed on the screen – that is OS specific, though, on Windows, you might use `getch` from `conio.h` header.
- User input needs to be buffered, and you might need special handling for user deleting characters (necessary) or using arrows to move the cursor around (for simplicity, you might just not support, but user will be less satisfied then).
- When outputting own data, overwrite user input (you might just move cursor with [ansi escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)), but make sure you clear out all data written, i. e. overwrite with additional whitespace, if necessary.
- Then re-print the user's input into next line.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you want some kind of GUI to do this, that way the input and output areas are separated rather than using a command line program.

You can directly write to the terminal using a buffer, this is OS specific. In theory you can use the top half of the console window for input and the bottom half for output. This is allot of work though, and would be similar to making a console game
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions

Alternatively you can use the console for input and write the results to a .txt file